# How to replace seconds to 00 in OffsetDateTime.now()

Tags: java, spring, rest-assured

I am using below code to remove milliseconds and set the seconds to zero but it does not set seconds to zero

```
**time = OffsetDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS).withSecond(0)**
```

Is there a way i can set the seconds to zero in OffSetDateTime.now()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're using should normally put your seconds to zero. However, try using `withNano(0)` too, which will remove everything after the minutes

```
// Prints 2021-02-11T22:55:00.591+01:00
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS).withSecond(0));
// Prints 2021-02-11T22:55+01:00
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS).withSecond(0).withNano(0));
```